Power BI M code Split column from Lowercase to Uppercase won't include diacritics (accents)
In Power BI, I have a column that I need to split all values from Lowercase to Uppercase:
Column1
Blue
Blue
Energy
Energy
BlueÉnergie
Énergie
ConformitéBlue
Blue
ConformitéÉnergie
Énergie

The obvious solution is to use the built in function which ends up looking like this:
= Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"a".."z"}, {"A".."Z"}), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"})

The problem is that I don't get the expected result, ending up with this:



Column1.1
Column1.2




Blue
Energy


Blue
null


Energy
null


Energy
Blue


BlueÉnergie
null


Énergie
Blue


ConformitéBlue
null


Blue
Conformité


ConformitéÉnergie
null


Énergie
Conformité



when the expected result should be :



Column1.1
Column1.2




Blue
Energy


Blue
null


Energy
null


Energy
Blue


Blue
Énergie


Énergie
Blue


Conformité
Blue


Blue
Conformité


Conformité
Énergie


Énergie
Conformité



How can I get the expected result as concisely as possible such that the column will properly split from ALL lowercase characters to ALL uppercase characters?
Note: spaces and special characters do appear in my data set so I cannot split on any delimiters

@michal is on the right track but rather than list out every character, you can use the unicode blocks. See https://powerquery.how/character-fromnumber/.
When you write {"a".."z"}, under the covers, PQ is saying get me the unicode block from 66 to 91. You can leverage this by seeing other unicode blocks here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters and just use the start and end characters for each block you want to insert. i.e. {"Ā".."ſ"} gets you 192 to 319 which is extended latin containing cedillas,acutes,carons etc

Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement, Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"a".."z", "à".."ÿ"}, {"A".."Z", "À".."Ÿ"}) would work here, right?

Probably. Hard to say without seeing all of OP's data.

Right, looked like French though.

In the Unicode character set, it appears there are 1,791 Upper Case characters and 2,155 Lower Case characters. See Unicode Character Categories. Not that hard to create a list of all upper and lowercase and use that in the Splitter function. Of course, you may not need all of them.

Interesting, I've never seen that happen (but I'm a Power Query newb and don't really work with non-English alphabets).
Edit, this is much easier (but needs to be maintained):
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    SplitTextWithDiacritics = Table.SplitColumn(
        Source, 
        "Column1", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition(
            {"a".."z", "à", "á", "â", "ã", "ä", "å", "è", "é", "ê", "ë", "ì", "í", "î", "ï", "ò", "ó", "ô", "õ", "ö", "ù", "ú", "û", "ü", "ç", "ñ"}, 
            {"A".."Z", "À", "Á", "Â", "Ã", "Ä", "Å", "È", "É", "Ê", "Ë", "Ì", "Í", "Î", "Ï", "Ò", "Ó", "Ô", "Õ", "Ö", "Ù", "Ú", "Û", "Ü", "Ç", "Ñ"}
        ),
        {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"}
    )
in
    SplitTextWithDiacritics

Anyway, this is a little clunky but seems to work:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    AddCustom = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each 
        let
            text = [Column1],
            len = Text.Length(text),
            result = 
                List.Accumulate({1..len}, {"", ""}, (state, current) =>
                    let
                        char = Text.Middle(text, current - 1, 1),
                        prevChar = if current > 1 then Text.Middle(text, current - 2, 1) else "",
                        isUpper = Text.Upper(char) = char and Text.Lower(char) <> char and Text.Lower(prevChar) = prevChar and Text.Upper(prevChar) <> prevChar,
                        newState = if isUpper then 
                                    {state{0} & state{1}, char} 
                                  else 
                                    {state{0}, state{1} & char}
                    in
                        newState
                ),
            finalResult = if result{0} = "" then {text, null} else result
        in
            finalResult
    ),
    AddColumns = Table.AddColumn(AddCustom, "Column1.1", each [Custom]{0}),
    AddColumn2 = Table.AddColumn(AddColumns, "Column1.2", each try [Custom]{1} otherwise null),
    RemoveColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(AddColumn2, {"Custom"})
in
    RemoveColumns

Or slightly differently:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    
    AddCustom = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each 
        let
            text = [Column1],
            result = 
                List.Accumulate({1..Text.Length(text)}, {"", ""}, (state, current) =>
                    let
                        char = Text.Middle(text, current - 1, 1),
                        prevChar = if current > 1 then Text.Middle(text, current - 2, 1) else "",
                        isUpper = Text.Upper(char) = char and Text.Lower(prevChar) = prevChar and Text.Upper(prevChar) <> prevChar,
                        newState = if isUpper then {state{0} & state{1}, char} else {state{0}, state{1} & char}
                    in
                        newState
                )
        in
            if result{0} = "" then {text, null} else result
    ),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(AddCustom, {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Custom.1", "Custom.2"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Custom.1", type text}, {"Custom.2", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"

